# undefined variable error in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, global-variables, undefined

I have this code and I want to show `il` in the elements which will be created by jquery , but `il`  is undefined  :
this is code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var il = 1 ;
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li>Appended item " + il + " </li>");
var il = il + 1;
    });
});
</script>


<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<ol>
  <li>List item 1</li>
  <li>List item 2</li>
  <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button id="btn1">Append text</button>
<button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
```

this is output :

```
List item 1
List item 2
List item 3
Appended item undefined
Appended item undefined
```

Comment: Live: http://jsfiddle.net/pf0y6z4q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use il++.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var il = 1 ;
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li>Appended item " + il + " </li>");
        il++;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `var` from `var il = il + 1;`.

Use `var` only for new variable declaration.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var il = 1 ;
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("p").append(" <b>Appended text</b>.");
    });
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li>Appended item " + il + " </li>");
        il = il + 1;
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uf11d39f/)